# javafx application run error Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to run a small javafx application using terminal.But i get this error.

```
root@abc-abc2051A:~# java -jar --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules javafx.controls myjar-1.0.0-shaded.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib
```

My ubunt Environment

- OS - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Architecture 64bit
- Java - OpenJDK 1.8.0_362

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Hmmm... this appears to be a cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72591758/111175